# Finding Multivariable limits using polar coordinates

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

How do I find the limit of this multivariable function as it goes to zero using polar coordinates?

$$ \frac{\sin (x^2 + y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use 
\begin{align}
 x &= r \cos \theta \\
 y &= r \sin \theta
\end{align}
So $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ hence
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sin (x^2 + y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}
 =
 \frac{\sin r^2}{r^4}
\end{equation}
Using L'Hopital twice, we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin r^2}{r^4}
\sim
\frac{2\cos\left(r^2\right)-4r^2\sin\left(r^2\right)}{12r^2}
\rightarrow 
+\infty
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid polar coordinates in that case indeed

$$(x,y) \to 0 \iff t=x^2+y^2 \to 0^+$$

therefore by standard limit

$$\frac{\sin (x^2 + y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}=\frac{\sin t}{t^2}=\frac 1t \cdot \frac{\sin t}t\to \infty $$

Comment: nice trick for the $t$ !!

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Yes in that case it is pretty straightforward to reconduct to one variable limit! Thanks for the appreciation, Bye